# How can I redirect a URL to YouTube using PHP?

Tags: php, url, redirect

Problem im facing

- when we retrieve url of say   http://youtu.be/YFZ2L0sNzvM?a its being redirected.
- when we retrieve wrong url say http://t.co/hNLWmspb when i copy paste this url on browser its redirects   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XzqagJTsNrc&feature=youtu.be.
- so i have retrieve http://t.co/hNLWmspb  so how could redirect link to you url.

Bug in This Line

```
           /* bug in this line */
         /* $media_url = 'http://t.co/hNLWmspb' */
           /**  how to solve this issue when url is retrive that is not you redirection url.*/

            <a href='.$media_url.' class="html5lightbox" data-group=""
              titl="'.$tweet_content.'">';
```

source code

```
     if(isset($row['videoUrl']) && $row['videoUrl']!='null')
        {

            $v = $row['videoUrl'];
            $v_url=array();
            $v_url=explode(",",$v);
            foreach($v_url as $video_url)
            {

                $video_url = str_replace('http://vimeo.com','//player.vimeo.com/video',$video_url);
                $video_url = explode('&',$video_url);
                $media_url=$video_url[0];

                // echo strtok('?v=');
                 if( ($x_pos = strpos($media_url, '?v=')) !== FALSE ){
                    $default_image = '"http://img.youtube.com/vi/'.substr($media_url, $x_pos + 3).'/0.jpg"';
                    if( ($x_pos1 = strpos($default_image, '#')) !== FALSE ){
                        //echo substr($default_image, 0,$x_pos1);
                        $default_image=substr($default_image, 0,$x_pos1).'/0.jpg"';
                    }

                 }


            }//foreach of $v_url
            //echo $media_url;$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);
            $tweet_content="
                <div style='display: block; overflow: hidden; margin:0 8px 8px 8px;' id='html5-text'>
                <p id='boxscroll' class='twt' style='overflow: hidden; font-size:.9em; line-height:1.5em;margin-bottom:.5em!important' tabindex='5000;'>".htmlentities($this->linkify($row['tweetText']))."
                <div class='twtdetail' style='font-size:.9em; line-height:1em'>
                <img width='45' src=". $row['profileImageUrl']."
                class='image round left' style='margin:0 .5em 0 0!important'> ".htmlentities($row['name'])."<br><span class='via' style='font-size:.8em'>via Twitter<br>".$this->twitter_time($row['tweetedAt'])."</span>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>";
            $content='<div class="4u"><div class="box photo tile">

            /* bug in this line */
            /* $media_url = 'http://t.co/hNLWmspb' */
          /**  how to solve this issue when url is retrive that is not you redirection url.*/

                <a href='.$media_url.' class="html5lightbox" data-group=""
                  titl="'.$tweet_content.'">'; 
            if(strpos($media_url, 'youtube')){
                $content.='<span class="video"></span><img src='.$default_image.' style="width:100%; height:155px" class="image" >';
            }else{
                $content.='<span class="video"></span><img src='.$default_image.' style="width:100%; height:155px" class="image" >';
            }           

            $content.='</a></div></div>';

            $html[$n]=$content;
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: I hope I'm not the only one who does not understand this question.

Comment: problem is when we retrieve  http://t.co/hNLWmspb that is not redirect url of you tube what should we do to redirect t you tube url.

Comment: i have edit my question now its clear i we have non you tube redirtion url how t redirect that.